Change the color of the Button
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
OutFile "Test.exe"

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE "Welcome to the Example Installer"
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "This is an example NSIS installer."

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 7u 10u 100u 12u "My Button"
    Pop $1
    SetCtlColors $1 0x00FF00 0x00FF00
    ${NSD_OnClick} $1 MyButtonClick

    ${NSD_CreateNumber} 10U 25% 100u 12u "Message Here"
    Pop $2
    SetCtlColors $2 0x00FF00 0x000000  ; Set the numeric control color

    nsDialogs::Show
SectionEnd

Function MyButtonClick
    # Button click handler
FunctionEnd

In this code, I'm trying to change the button color. But the color is changing only on the border.
I need the modified code to change the color of the button

Windows does not really support changing the color of buttons, you need to fully draw the button yourself to do so.
You can try one of the skinning plug-ins (or this commercial product) but unless you are changing the colors of all other elements as well, I would advise against it.
